# Angularjs ui router manual navigation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to manually change the current state within my controller using the ui router.

I have the following code at the moment:

```
<button ng-click="go()">Go</button>

    controllers.controller("MyController", function($scope){
        $scope.go = function(){
            //Manually change state
        };
    });
```

Is there something like

```
$uiRouter.changeState("mystate"); ?
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just use the `ui-sref` directive eg `<a ui-sref="myState">go</a>`

Comment: Because I needed to do some actions before changing the state (registering an user for example before changing the state).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use `$state.go` or `$state.transitionTo` (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#statetransitiontoto-toparams--options)

```
controllers.controller("MyController", function($scope, $state){
    $scope.go = function(){
        $state.go('new-state');
    };
});
```